# Overriding of factory methods: how to return the child class object type?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, overriding, factory-pattern

Let's suppose I have a parent class in PHP like this:

```
class A {

    private $property;

    public static function factory($arg) {
        $object = new A();
        $object->property = $arg;
        return $object;
    }

}
```

And I want to extend it in this way:

```
class B extends A {

    public static function factory() {
        return parent::factory('constant');
    }

}
```

When I do `B::factory()` I get a object of type `A`. What if I want an object of type `B`? **I cannot change anything in the code of class `A`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1st version

That's because you hardcoded the `A` class in the factory method.
In class `A`, instead of `$object = new A()` try (require Php 5.3):

```
$class_name = get_called_class();
$object = new $class_name;
```

[`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/get_called_class) "Gets the name of the class the static method is called in."

Shorter version:

```
$object = new static();
```

#### 2nd version (hardcoded parent class):

Copy object properties manually:

```
$parent = parent::factory($args);
$obj = new static();
$obj->setTimestamp($parent->getTimestamp());
$obj->setTimezone($parent->getTimezone());
return $obj;
```

Or use an hack to do it autoatically:

> [How to Cast Objects in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226103/how-to-cast-objects-in-php)

Comment: I omitted something important (I'm realizing it now because of your answer) in my question. A is a standard PHP library class.

Comment: well then i'll duplicate the code in A::factory (if you know it?) into B. but with new static() instead of new A() in case you make subclass of it later

Comment: I don't know the code, as I said, `A` is in fact a PHP standard lib class. I solved creating a `new B()` and then copying all relevant properties into it (they are a few).

Comment: DateTime. Once you set timezone and timestamp, you can consider the object successfully cloned.

Comment: well then I'll call the parent factory to create a temporary object and next I'll get/set relevant properties (see original answer)

Comment: It's what I already did in the hope there will be more elegant solutions. It seems there are not, so I'm going to accept your answer because of your help and because, in fact, it's the only way to go manage the problem.

Comment: answers to this question might be interesting for you because it provide a generic solution for cloning object properties from a class to another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226103/how-to-cast-objects-in-php . but it's not a perfect solution either

Answer (score 0):

In your example:

1. You have two classes (unleast)
2. both classes can be instantiated (concrete, not pure or abstract)
3. one class is a superclass of another
4. both classes are instantiated with a "factory" method
5. the "factory" method of a subclass can invoke the the "factory" method of the  superclass
6. each "factory" method can have several type or count of parameters

**Problem**

Now, this is what it got my attention:

```
class B extends A {

    public static function factory() {
        return parent::factory('constant');
    }

}
```

**Short & Quick answer:**

Change that to:

```
class B extends A {

    public static function factory() {
        return A::factory('constant');
    }

}
```

**Long boring hipster extended answer:**

You are attempting to overriding ( and overloading, with different parameters ) a static function.

Its a common mistake, that assume that static methods are virtual, and can be overrided. Some programming languages allow that (Object Pascal, Delphi), other don't (C#, Java), PHP depends on the version, I think.

To be honest, "static functions" work similar like global functions with a namespace, that have public access to all members of a class, Instead of methods. I suggest to see them as global functions, always.

Cheers.

Comment: Ok, but, I can't get why your code will solve my problem. For me, using `parent` or `A` is exactly equivalent.

Comment: @lorenzo-s No, wait. It depends on your PHP version, as mentioned in other post. "A::" is version independent. "parent::" will work as "A::", in some versions, and as "B::" in others. Cheers

Comment: In which versions `parent` is equivalent to `B::`?