# Can I cast parent record object to child record when using concrate table inheritance?

Tags: php, inheritance, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I can't seem to find a proper way to cast a parent record object to a child record object.

My models look like this:

```
ModelA:
  columns:
    col_a:integer

ModelB:
  inheritance:
    type:             concrete
    extends:          ModelA
  columns:
    col_b:integer
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
$instanceB = (ModelB) $instanceA->copy();
$instanceB->setColB('whatever');
$instanceB->save();
```

Basically I need to copy all fields and relations in from instance A to instance B without having to hardcode the fields and relations.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC there is no object to object casting in php ([there are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226103/how-to-cast-objects-in-php) some hacky solutions though). You can copy all properties of a model object to an another e.g. like this:

```
$b = new ModelB();
$b->fromArray($instanceA->toArray());
$b->setColB('yepp')->save();
```