# PHP multiple child classes, accessing child class to class

Tags: php, class, oop, parent-child

I'm not entirely sure if this a understanding problem or syntax.
I am trying to access child classes from other child classes under the same parent.

```
    class TopLevel {
    foreach (glob("assets/php/*.php") as $filename) // will get all .php files within plugin directory
      {
        include $filename;
        $temp = explode('/',$filename);
        $class_name = str_replace('.php','',$temp[count($temp)-1]); // get the class name 
        $this->$class_name = new $class_name;   // initiating all plugins
      }
    }

    class A extends TopLevel {
        $var = 'something';
        public function output() {
            return $this->var;
        }
    }

    class B extends TopLevel {
        // This is where I need help, CAN the child class A be accessed sideways from class B? Obviously they need to be loaded in correct order of dependency.
        $this->A->output();
    }
```

I don't see why this shouldn't work. Not very good structure but its a single object application.

Comment: There is no relation between A and B as far as I can see?

Comment: Also you might want to look into [proper autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php) instead of whatever it is your doing now.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, but what you're trying to do should work if the foreach is in the constructor of the TopLevel class.

Comment: I used this autoloding because it initiates the sub class as an object inside the main. Like I said, this structure is not correct. The relation for example would be template data in class A and the flow/logic is in Class B.

Comment: I was not asking about that kind of relation. How would instance A be aware of instance B. Or the other way around?

Comment: Opps your right, They don't directly, only via parent. I did type $self there, as stated could simply be syntax error; but its not normal structure of code. It should be parent::A->output(); 

TopLevel has each child stored, I have tried with parent but it results in same non-object.

Comment: @EricSamuel : At least care to check ansewrs or we just wasted time reading and answering your question?

Comment: Ok, sorry. Tried to up click but I guess its the check. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: No, the child class A cannot be accessed sideways.  There is no direct inheritance between A and B.

The answer might be to typecast $this->A into an object of type B using a function like the one in the answer to this question:

[How to Cast Objects in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226103/how-to-cast-objects-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Make object of class A inside B and then call method of A as there is No parent child relationship between A , B.

```
   $objOfA = new A();
   $objOfA->output();
```