# Multiple Array elements to Class Object

Tags: php, oop

What is best practices to convert multiple array objects into class objects?

I have following use case,

```
class Queue {
    private $id;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    private $name;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
    public static function getAll( ) {

        // Guzzle HTTP Request returns JSON 
        $responseArray = json_decode ( $response->getBody() );
    }

}
```

This is part of composer package. So now when using this `Queue` we can request multiple `Queues` from parent application. Now how do i convert this json response to `Queue` Object.

Also is it a good decision to declare `getAll()` method static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the JSON response contains an associative array, with the keys being the property names you want in your object. If so, you can use the solution found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1869147/377628). Basically, you just iterate through the array and use the key found in your array as the property name and the value as the property value:

```
$queue = new Queue();
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    $queue->$key = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What @Hassan says is true, if the keys are not the same or overlap than you can use [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226103/how-to-cast-objects-in-php). You basically need to cast the object given by `json_decode` to the `Queu` object and return it.

Static in this case makes sense, because you will create and return a Queu object here, if you first need to make the Queu object and than return another one, it makes little sense.