# How to cast type by the object that is to be assigned?

Tags: php

I need to do something like:

```php
$object = (typeof($object))$value;
```

Knowing that both `$object` and `$value` are scalar types.

Comment: this is not possible in PHP
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226103/how-to-cast-objects-in-php

you need to write our own casting function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$copy = $value;
if(settype($copy, gettype($object)))
    $object = $copy;
```